# Align and size buttons to the textbox above it

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I am using `Qt qml` to design a very simple user interface. The QML is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 800; height: 600    

    ColumnLayout {
       anchors.centerIn: parent 
       spacing: 25

       TextField {
        placeholderText: qsTr("User name")
        width: 200
       }

        TextField {
         placeholderText: qsTr("Password")
         width: 200
         echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }

        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text: "Log In"
            }

            Button {
                text: "Cancel"
            }        
        }   
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is ensure that both the buttons take the same size and they occupy the same amount of space horizontally as the `TextField` components. Is it possible to achieve this using QML?

Comment: Could you provide an image of the required output?

Comment: The answer from Florian solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just resize the Layout to the wanted width and use the attached property `Layout.fillWidth: true` to expand / reduce the size of the Item. Just updated your example to illustrate:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 800; height: 600

    ColumnLayout {
        width: 200
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 25

        TextField {
            placeholderText: qsTr("User name")
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        TextField {
            placeholderText: qsTr("Password")
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }
        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text: "Log In"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            Button {
                text: "Cancel"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: It's not needed in a child-layout where `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight` is set by default.

If you have any questions on that feel free to ask...

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to give an `id` to your `TextField`

```
TextField {
    id: myTextField
    ...
}
```

and reference the width of your `TextField` in your `Button`:

```
Button{
    ...
    width: myTextField.width
}
```

Comment: Doing this just makes the two buttons overlap. There must be a better way to align them. Also, if you have spacing, this all gets very ugly. I tried `GridLayout` but no dice so far.